# many to many with common where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

```
+------+--------+---------+
| id   | teacher|student  |
+-------+-------+---------+
| 1    | 1      |1        |
| 2    | 3      |3        |
| 3    | 3      |4        |
| 4    | 3      |5        |
| 5    | 3      |6        |
| 6    | 4      |5        |
| 7    | 4      |6        |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

This being a many-to-many association table, how do i query a list of student where they have common teacher of e.g. 3 **and** 4?

I am expecting to be able to get student 5 and 6, since they are both "sharing" the same teacher?

what i have currently is

`SELECT ts.studentId, ts.teacherId
FROM teacher_students ts
group by ts.studentId, ts.teacherId
having ts.teacherId in (3,4);`

But i'm getting student 3,4,5,6 instead of 5,6

Comment: How are you executing this query?  Directly from MySQL?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregaiton

```
 select studentId from teacher_students t
 where t.teacherId in (3,4)
 group by t.studentId
 having count(distinct t.teacherId )=2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70b3b2de9695f2f567afeaee7ec37bda

```
     studentId
       5
       6
```

Comment: i cant be using having count = 2, as the teacherId is "in" and it can be 1 to 10 teacher ids

Comment: @LeeGary https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70b3b2de9695f2f567afeaee7ec37bda does not you want this result

Comment: @LeeGary according to your sample data and expected output we thought about the solution but if you have many more that should have to share with us ,then we can guide to you

Comment: it almost works, but it failed when i only put in 1 teacher id, if i enter teacher 3 in your demo, it should return 3,4,5,6

Comment: @LeeGary https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70b3b2de9695f2f567afeaee7ec37bda can you put your sample here in this link and give me

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0f8b2236758e88e6debf12415c875f2 it should return 3 and 4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180038/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-lee-gary).

Comment: @LeeGary https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a12e210a5e490dca37da640430dfeb2 its returning 3,4

Answer (score 2):

Here is one canonical way to do this:

```
SELECT studentId
FROM teacher_students
WHERE teacherId IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY studentId
HAVING MIN(teacherId) <> MAX(teacherId);
```

[image]

### Demo

One advantage of the above query is that it is index friendly.  More generally, if you wanted students having say three or more common teachers, then you could use this:

```
SELECT studentId
FROM teacher_students
WHERE teacherId IN (...)      -- some_num of teachers
GROUP BY studentId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teacherId) = some_num;
```

Comment: same as the answer above.. the count of teacher can' be used as a predicate, since it's dynamic, it can be `teacherId in (1,2,3,4)`

Comment: Maybe you should tell us how or from where you would be executing this query.  If you're using a statement, then you would need to parameterize the teacher IDs _and_ the number of teachers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `where` clause with `exists` :

```
SELECT ts.*
FROM teacher_students ts
WHERE teacherId IN (3,4) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM teacher_students ts1 
              WHERE ts.studentId = ts1.studentId AND ts.teacherId <> ts1.teacherId
             );
```